# Windows - Logging changes to Certificate Store

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, pki

In Windows there is a Certificate Store, where users and admins (depending on the setup) can make their changes: add root CA, modify CRL, etc. It seems to be quite a critical place in system security. So I come to the question:

Can Windows be set up to log changes to Certificate Store to its standard log fcility, EventLog?

Till now I only managed to get a *certificate removed* event (ID 1004) from `CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle` log, but nothing about *certificate added* or anything else.

Upd.: I tried both Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 and got same results.

Upd.2: Just tried also on a fresh Windows 8 installation: got same results. What should be configured to enable these logs?

Answer (score 2):

I have confirmed Windows Server 2012 R2 and 2016 provide event data for:

```
1001 Certificate Replaced  
1002 Certificate Expired  
1003 Certificate Expiration Approaching  
1004 Certificate Deleted  
1005 Certificate Archived  
1006 Certificate Installed
```

With the same level of details (Subject, Thumbprint, EKU, Expiration, subject account).

You probably need to provide more details about your platform and environment.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14250.certificate-services-lifecycle-notifications.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Greg. I tried Windows 2012R2 and Windows 10. Can you share the configuration you made that enabled these events logging please?

Comment: I'm not aware of any configuration required to enable these events. You could try increasing the log size (default size is 1 MByte). Also confirm you are checking the appropriate log (System or User).

Comment: These logs contain only a few certificate deletion entries and nothing more on my test systems, so they defenitely fit the log file size. I checked all `CertificateServicesClient-Lifecycle` logs - still cannot find the other events.

Comment: In the wiki link, notice what is stated beneath the events list table: (1) Except for expiration and close to expiration notifications, only certificates in MY store are covered. (2) Only certificates exported with private keys generate the exported event.